# scorm 1.2 prerequisite element in scorm 2004 3rd edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have a question about scorm.

the following code is a prerequisite in scorm 1.2:

*activity1 & activity2*

what is the corresponding code in scorm 2004 3rd edition?